# Creating 2 strings out of 1 recursively

Tags: python, string, tuples

I'm trying to write a program that takes a string(stringg) apart and creates 1 string with all uppercase letters in stringg and 1 string with all lowercase letters in stringg.

result should be something like this:

```
split_rec('HsaIm') = ('HI', 'sam')
```

This is how I have tried to write it recursively.

```
def split_rec(stringg):

    if not stringg: 
        return ('')
    elif stringg[0].isupper() == True and stringg[0].isalpha() == True:
        return stringg[0] + split_rec(stringg[1:]), split_rec(stringg[1:])
    elif stringg[0].isupper() == False and stringg[0].isalpha() == True:
        return split_rec(stringg[1:]), stringg[0] + split_rec(stringg[1:])
```

But when I try it I get the error code "Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly". Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: your recursion logic is not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First avoid test like so:

```
if condition == True:
```

and write simply

```
if condition:
```

Then you need to return a tuple and access the result as a tuple in all cases:

```
def split_rec(stringg):

    if not stringg: 
        return ('','')
    else:
        first = stringg[0]
        assert first.isalpha(), "The string contains invalid characters."
        upper, lower = split_rec(stringg[1:])
        if first.isupper():
            return first + upper, lower
        else:
            return upper, first + lower
```

Answer (score 1):

```
split_rec = lambda x: tuple(map(''.join, zip(*[(a,'') if a.isupper() else ('',a) for a in x if a.isalpha()])))

>>> split_rec('HsaIm')
('HI', 'sam')
```

This takes your string and sorts each letter as upper or lower case by putting it on the right or left side of a tuple. Then it unzips the tuples (using `zip(*[...])`), applies a `join` function to each to make them back into strings and then makes the whole thing a tuple again.

Just in case you needed a one-line solution

Comment: Nice one-liner, but I would probably be a good idea to also show him how to do this within a function, since that is what he was using.

Comment: Good point. I think though, that if Goshaaz wants a function (not a `lambda`) then Arun Ghosh's solution does essentially the same thing as mine.  The only difference is that mine takes advantage of `zip` to get everything on one line.

Comment: Not sure that one liners just for the sake of one lining is necessary a good thing, you loose a lot of readability IMO. Also this is not a recursive function, which I assume is what the OP wants.

Comment: I completely agree, one-lining for its own sake is not good practice. Julien Bernu's answer is definitely the one that should be accepted here; its recursive and solves the problem clearly. I believe that @Goshaaz should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Julien's answer. However, sometimes its nice to see different ways of solving the same problem isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with you recursion logic and it can easily be done without recursion like:

```
def split_rec(stringg):
    alphas = [x for x in stringg if x.isalpha()]
    lower = [x for x in alphas if not x.isupper() ]
    upper = [x for x in alphas if x.isupper() ]
    return (''.join(upper), ''.join(lower))
```